# AuthenticationState is not persisted after navigation

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have following custom login added to index.razor of default Blazor app template (without auth).

```
<form>
    <button @onclick="SignIn">Sign in</button>
</form>
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@code {
    private string userName = "FakeUser";

    private async Task SignIn(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var fakeUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
        }, "Fake authentication type"));

        var provider = (IHostEnvironmentAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider;
        //provider is ServerAuthenticationStateProvider

        provider.SetAuthenticationState(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(fakeUser)));

        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        //authState.User.Identity.Name == "Fake User" - this is ok
    }
}
```

However when I navigate to another page, the authState is not persisted:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    //authState.User.Identity.Name == null ??
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the `<button>` inside native `<form>` element, because it submits the form (reloads page)

```
<form>
    <button @onclick="SignIn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Solution:

Either use [<EditForm>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or

```
<button type="button" @onclick="SignIn">Sign in</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and it does persist the Authentication State...

Here's my code:

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@using System.Security.Claims;

<button @onclick="SignIn">Sign in</button>

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

@code {
    private string userName = "FakeUser";

    private async Task SignIn(MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      var fakeUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
     {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
     }, "Fake authentication type"));

    var provider = 
    (IHostEnvironmentAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthenticationStateProvider;
    //provider is ServerAuthenticationStateProvider

    provider.SetAuthenticationState(Task.FromResult(new 
                                         AuthenticationState(fakeUser)));

    var authState = await 
               AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
               Console.WriteLine(authState.User.Identity.Name);


   }
}
```

### Counter.razor

```
    @page "/counter"

    @inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider


   @code {

         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
         {
              var authState = await 
                   AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
              Console.WriteLine(authState.User.Identity.Name);
   }
 }
```

Please, run your app, click the button element, then press the "Counter" menu item in the NavMenu to navigate to the Counter component... go now to the Output window and see if the word FakeUser was printed twice.

Comment: Well, doesn't work for me. Can you share your entire project somewhere? Or at least your startup.cs

Comment: Ah, my signin button element was inside form element which reloads entire page which causes to reset the state